# Customized ng-repeat attr directive with transcluding elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, coffeescript, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-transclude

OK, I swear I've searched all over SO for answers to this.  Each answer I'm finding is almost, but not quite, exactly not what I'm looking for.

## Goal

I'm trying to write some directives that let me DRY up the way I display collections.  Final goal is to be able to do things in the view or another directive that looks like:

```
<md-grid-tile index='event' index-by='isPublic' index-key='true'>
  <md-grid-tile-header>{{event.name}}</md-grid-tile-header>
  <md-grid-tile-footer>
    <profile-card index='eventOwner' index-by='event_id' index-key='event.$id' collection='profile'>
      arbitrary transcluded content that uses {{profile}}
    </profile-card>
  </md-grid-tile-footer>
</md-grid-tile>
```

`md-grid-tile-*` all come from angular-material, and do fancy transcluding things with their contents.
`profile-card` is some arbitrary custom directive that wraps transcluded content.  E.g. i have a common card to display profile info, but i want to put different action buttons on it depending on where i'm placing it.

I'm trying to create the `index` directive, which will act like a very focused ng-repeat.  In this example:

- The attrs on `md-grid-tile` element tell it to repeat over every `event` with an `isPublic` of `true`.
- On the `profile-card` element, it will find all `eventOwner` objects with an `event_id` matching the `event.$id` of the containing element.  It will then repeat the `profile` objects that those `eventOwner` objects reference.

## Problems

I've got no problems with hooking up to the data sources, where I run into problems is:

- Creating multiple elements in the DOM in the right place
- Repeating elements that transclude content

For the purposes of code samples here I am simplifying the data sources.  `mockProvider` will be replaced with a service that creates the collection based on the `index-*` attrs.

### Attempt #1

```
.directive 'index', ['mockProvider', (mockProvider)->
  restrict: 'A'
  priority: 1
  compile: (el,attrs)->

    el.attr 'ng-repeat', 'item in collection'

    post: (scope,el,attrs,ctrl,transclude)->
      scope.collection = mockProvider
]
```

I still haven't been able to figure out why I can't get this approach to work.  The `ng-repeat` attr gets properly attached, but nothing is repeated.

### Attempt #2

```
.directive 'index', ['mockProvider', (mockProvider)->
  restrict: 'A'
  priority: 1 # tried with 1, 1001, -1000
  compile: (el,attrs)->
    post: (scope,el,attrs,ctrl,transclude)->
      scope.collection = mockProvider
      newEl = angular.element el[0].outerHTML
      newEl.attr 'ng-repeat', 'foo in [1,2,3]'
      newEl.removeAttr 'pb-index'
      el.replaceWith $compile(newEl[0].outerHTML)(scope)
]
```

This repeats a bunch of stuff, but then explodes with: `[ngTransclude:orphan] Illegal use of ngTransclude directive in the template! No parent directive that requires a transclusion found.`  It seems like the re-compilation somehow loses the transcluded content?  I've also seen other SO comments that warn against this due to inefficiency.

### Attempt #3

```
.directive 'index', ['mockProvider', (mockProvider)->
  restrict: 'A'
  priority: 1001
  compile: (el,attrs)->
    post: (scope,el,attrs,ctrl,transclude)->
      el.html ""
      scope.collection = mockProvider
      scope.$watchCollection 'collection', (collection)->
        for item,index in collection
          childScope = scope.$new()
          childScope.item = item
          transclude childScope, (newElement)->
            el.append newElement
```

Finally, I tried a naive re-implementation of `ng-repeat`.  This has gotten the closest, but still isn't working, and requires a bunch more code to get it to match the performance/functionality of `ng-repeat`.

## HOW???

Am I totally on the wrong track?  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What is `pbIndex` - is this the same as `profile-chip`? I'm still confused about exactly what you are trying to achieve. Can you remove all the `md-*` stuff and services and for the purposes of the question, just simply hard-code the collections that you are referring to. You also talk about "transcluding" but nowhere do you specify `transclude: true` and you actually don't have any content under `<profile-chip>` that you intend to transclude - so, it's hard to understand what you are getting at

Comment: sorry for that -- i just tried to clear up a few things in the OP.

`index` is the attr-based generic directive i'm trying to create.
`md-grid-tile` and `profile-card` are examples of directives that use transclusion.  Any directive that transcludes will serve.

I know how to get the actual collection based on the `index-*` attributes.  The problem is getting the `index` directive to actually repeat a transcluding element that it's attached to.

Comment: so what's the problem?